# HTML files are downloaded instead of rendered in browser using NGINX

Tags: html, ubuntu, nginx

My `contact.html` file is being downloaded rather than rendered in the browser when running my site on NGINX.`home.html` is working properly. This is how my `default` (in folder `sites-available`) file looks like:

```
server {
    listen 90;
    listen [::]:90;

    server_name example.com;
    root /home/myname/www;

    location / {

    try_files $uri /home.html;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *; 
    }

    location = /contact {
     default_type text/html;
     alias /home/myname/www/contact.html;


    }
}
```

When I add `/contact` to my url on my browser, `contact.html` gets downloaded as unknown file format. After having done an extensive search, these are the things I've tried:

1. Clear the browser cache (it also happens in Edge, so clearly this isn't the issue)
2. In `nginx.conf` I commented out the `default_type application/octet-stream` and un-commented `default_type text/html`
3. I have checked the in `mime.types` file the type `text/html` exists.
4. using `try_files $uri /contact.html`


   Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `default_type text/html` property in `nginx.conf` lives in `http {...}` block. Since my server is listening to port 90 this configuration does not apply. once I changed the port to 80 the issue was resolved.